# Getting all NOT matching entries across a link table in ms-access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have following relations in my database:
[image: relations]

There are different trainings in a company and they are repeated like 2-3 times a year.

Now I want to get all the tbl_events entries which a tbl_employee entry has NO relation to and display them in a report.

So far, I've tried to make a query giving me all the employess with the ev_name they already visited.

qry_visited:

```
SELECT tbl_employee.em_number
    ,tbl_event.ID AS ev_visited_id
FROM (
    tbl_event INNER JOIN tbl_date ON tbl_event.[ID] = tbl_date.[da_f_event]
    )
INNER JOIN (
    tbl_employee INNER JOIN tbl_training ON tbl_employee.[ID] = tbl_training.[tr_f_employee]
    ) ON tbl_date.[ID] = tbl_training.[tr_f_date];
```

And then I wrote a second query:
qry_unvisited

```
SELECT qry_visited.em_number
    ,tbl_event.ev_name
    ,qry_visited.ev_visited_id
FROM qry_visited
RIGHT JOIN tbl_event ON qry_visited.ev_visited_id = tbl_event.ID
WHERE (((qry_visited.ev_visited_id) IS NULL));
```

These queries only work together, if I limit the first one to only one employee. I would rather like to have one recordset with em_number and ev_name for all the employees.

I also researched for a couple of days now on working with (and working around) LEFT OUTER, RIGHT OUTER and FULL OUTER JOIN, but none did the trick.

Thanks for your help!

**edit 1**

Example:
There are 3 employees (emp1, emp2, epm3) and 3 events (ev1, ev2, ev3)

Let's say

- emp1 visited ev1 and ev2
- emp2 visited ev2 and ev3
- emp3 visited none so far

I want my result to look like this:

```
| employee | not visited events |
  emp1       ev3
  emp2       ev1
  emp3       ev1
  emp3       ev2
  emp3       ev3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a list of events with no related employees.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW tbl_event.*
FROM ((tbl_event
LEFT JOIN tbl_date ON tbl_event.ID = tbl_date.da_f_event)
LEFT JOIN tbl_training ON tbl_date.ID = tbl_training.tr_f_date)
LEFT JOIN tbl_employee ON tbl_training.tr_f_employee = tbl_employee.ID
WHERE tbl_employee.ID IS NULL
```

---

If I understand correctly, what you want is all possible employee-event combinations, excluding the ones which actually happened.

Something like this:

```
SELECT possibles.*
FROM (
    SELECT tbl_event.ID AS eventID, tbl_employee.ID AS empID
    FROM tbl_event, tbl_employee
) AS possibles
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tbl_date.da_f_event AS eventID, tbl_training.tr_f_employee AS empID
    FROM tbl_date
    INNER JOIN tbl_training ON tbl_date.ID = tbl_training.tr_f_date
) AS actuals ON possibles.eventID = actuals.eventID AND possibles.empID = actuals.empID
WHERE actuals.eventID IS NULL
```

You can add more fields from `tbl_event` and `tbl_employee` to the `possibles` subquery.

---

Following is an informal description of join types:

**`INNER JOIN`**

Includes only records which match on both sides of the join; duplicates the records for multiple matches

```
SELECT tbl_event.*, tbl_date.*
FROM tbl_event
INNER JOIN tbl_date ON tbl_event.ID = tbl_date.da_f_event
```

**`LEFT JOIN`**

Includes all records from the first table, and only records which match from the second table. Second-table columns for rows without a match in the second table will have a value of `NULL`. Duplicates the records for multiple matches.

```
SELECT tbl_event.*, tbl_date.*
FROM tbl_event
LEFT JOIN tbl_date ON tbl_event.ID = tbl_date.da_f_event
```

(There is also `RIGHT JOIN`, which does the same except it reverses the order of the tables. I haven't yet found any good reason to use `RIGHT JOIN`, so I suggest you avoid it.)

**`FULL OUTER JOIN`** (not supported by MS Access)

Includes all records from both tables even when there is no match for a given record on the other side of the join. Duplicates the records for multiple matches.

```
SELECT tbl_event.*, tbl_date.*
FROM tbl_event
FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_date ON tbl_event.ID = tbl_date.da_f_event
```

**Cross join**, AKA Cartesian product

Includes each record from the first table for each record in the second table.

```
SELECT tbl_event.*, tbl_date.*
FROM tbl_event, tbl_date
```

Comment: First off: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunatly I don't need the generally "unused" events but the unused events per employee. I will edit the question accordingly, to make it more clear...

Comment: @Argee Updated.

Comment: You, Sir, are a lifesaver! Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Argee Added description of joins

Comment: I hope your answer gets a few more upvotes; thanks for the overview... might be helpful in the future ;)